# Flexbox in IE doesn't set item widths correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to space some items properly within a div.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="action-box">
        <li class="long-item">Some cool info That needs to be on 2 lines</li>
        <li><a>Do a thing</a></li>
        <li><a>Do a different thing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <a>
        Do something different
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the all items the same size.

I tried setting the `flex-basis`, which works in chrome, but breaks horribly in IE.

https://jsfiddle.net/w71t2247/7/

I also tried setting the `max-width` on the long item, which works in IE, but is off center in chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/w71t2247/8/

I'm unsure how to handle this. I could browser hack it, but I feel like there is a cleaner way.

Comment: use *both* `max-width` and `flex-basis` together?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w71t2247/9/ still not centered, but consistent across browsers at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has lots of rendering problem with flexbox.

In this case, `flex-basis: 100%` seems to be the problem.

Instead, use `width: 100%`.

```
li {
  /* flex-basis: 100%; */
  width: 100%; /* new */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w71t2247/12/