# Creating flexbox tabs that shrink to content size

Tags: html, css, tabs, flexbox

My web layout uses flexbox. I'm trying to create a tab content component that will automatically size to the largest of its tab contents. I'd ideally also like it to fade between states. I'm trying to do this by using `position: absolute` to overlay `myTabContents1` and `myTabContents2` on top of each other. I then select the one that's visible by using `visibility` and `opacity`.

So the DOM looks basically like this (for simplicity here I'm only showing the contents of the tab pages, not the actual user controls for switching between them):

```
<div class='tabContentsList'>
    <div class='tabContentsItem'>
        Contents of first tab
    </div>
    <div class='tabContentsItem activeTab'>           
        Contents of second tab.
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
.tabContentsList {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tabContentsItem {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.3s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.tabContentsItem.activeTab {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

When you switch tabs, this correctly gives the fading effect. However, the `tabContentsList` element does not size to contain the `tabContentsItem` elements - it basically treats them as zero size so they end up overflowing their boundaries. I've tried replacing `right: 0` with `width: 100%` etc but that doesn't help. If you remove the `position: absolute` on the other hand, then the container expands to hold both tabs' contents, but the positioning is obviously incorrect - there's a blank space left for the invisible tab. Apparently there's a known conflict between `flexbox` and  `position: absolute`.

So is there another way to achieve this? For example is there another way to overlay the two tab contents that doesn't use `position: absolute` and that flexbox would respect? Seems like this would be a useful tool if it could be made to work.
Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Absolutely-positioned children of a flex container are removed from the normal flow of the document, so they are not considered flex items and don't participate in flex layout.

Comment: Consider posting a working demo. We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: inline-flex could help without absolute positionning https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gGGwog (do not use the toggle show/hide CSS , only there for demo)

Comment: @Michael_B: right - they don't participate in flex layout. So my question is whether there's a way to have a flexbox overlay another one without using absolute-positioning? I'll see about posting a demo - I didn't before because I don't know that my approach is even the right way to go.

Comment: @G-Cyr: I'm not seeing how inline-flex would help. In your demo the container changes size as the contents change, and that's what I'm trying to avoid - I want the container to size itself so that it's big enough to contain the maximum tab size, and then its size will be fixed as you switch tabs.

Comment: okay, then contents can be in absolute position 2 be sized according to the longest tab ....https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dVVgBJ I might have misunderstood what you lare trying to do ... short tabs can really shrink too little the whole thing to be readable at ease.

Comment: maybe a full example (html&css) with fake contents showing the whole thing you try to achieve would help to understand what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In general, and since absolute positioning take elements out of flow, it will make it difficult to create a solution where it size properly based of content, and most likely a script will be needed.

<strike>Another option is to use `transform` instead, for the positioning, where it will be possible to have the tab content elements sized equal.</strike>
Another option is to use negative margin instead, for the positioning, where it will be possible to have the tab content elements sized equal.

Here set `display: flex` on `tabs`/`tabscontent`, the `align-items`, which defaults to `stretch`, will keep them equally high.

The `flex: 0 0 100%` will tell the `tabcont1/2/3` to fill its parent width, and  with the <strike>`translateX()`</strike> negative margin we can then pull back the `tabcont2/3` in position.

*Note, since a `transition` on a transformed element move the text back and forth during the animation, more obvious in Chrome than the other browsers, I switched to using negative margins. When I find a way to avoid that, I'll update with both solutions.*

Stack snippet

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tabs-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

.tabs-wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabs > label {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

/*.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}*/

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tab" checked>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tab">
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tab">
  
  <div class="tabs">
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2, which is longer</label>
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  </div>

  <div class="tabscontent">
    <div class="tabcont1">Content 1</div>
    <div class="tabcont2">Content 2,<br>which is higher<br>than 1 and 3</div>
    <div class="tabcont1">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And if someone can't use Flexbox, you don't need to

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabs > label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}*/

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tab" checked>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tab">
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tab">
  
  <div class="tabs">
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label><!--
 --><label for="tab2">Tab 2, which is longer</label><!--
 --><label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  </div>

  <div class="tabscontent">
    <div class="tabcont1">Content 1</div><!--
 --><div class="tabcont2">Content 2,<br>which is higher<br>than 1 and 3</div><!--
 --><div class="tabcont1">Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated*

Here is an updated Flexbox version where the `container` is displayed as a flex column container, and with its `align-items` set to `flex-start`, it actually size the `tabcont1/2/3` based on content.

Each item will still be somewhat wider than the actual content, and need to, to have the same width so it is possible to position them left aligned using the negative margin (or `translate`).

The logic that Flexbox use to size comes from this post [Flexbox in IE doesn't set item widths correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493691/flexbox-in-ie-doesnt-set-item-widths-correctly)

So to finally make each item visually render properly, and extra wrapper, here a `span`, is used for padding and border.

*To be able to optimized this even more, as script will be needed.*

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.tabs-wrapper input {
  display: none;
}

.tabs-wrapper > div {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabs > label {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent {
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  display: flex;
}

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

/*.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}*/

.tabs-wrapper .tabscontent > div:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabs label:nth-child(3) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(1):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(1),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(2):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(2),
.tabs-wrapper input:nth-child(3):checked ~ .tabscontent > div:nth-child(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tab" checked>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tab">
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tab">
  
  <div class="tabs">
    <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    <label for="tab2">Tab 2, which is longer</label>
    <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
  </div>

  <div class="tabscontent">
    <div class="tabcont1"><span>Content 1</span></div>
    <div class="tabcont2"><span>Content 2,<br>with 2 lines</span></div>
    <div class="tabcont1"><span>Content 3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Your solution seems to work fine in the vertical direction. Is there any way to change it so it also simultaneously shrinks to the max content width in the horizontal direction?

Comment: @thund Practically, no, and this based on the fact that you won't be able to use negative margin or `translate`, to move it into is left position when its content size is not known. With a script, yes, still, a simple text line will still push it horizontally first, before it wraps, and how should the script _known_ when to break the line?

Comment: @thund Also note, the tabs themselves also create width, and how should the overall width relate to them? ... which should be prioritized?

Comment: Right, if the tabs themselves are wide enough to be a concern then the width of the entire component should properly be max(sum(tab widths), max(tab contents widths)). But for many use cases the tabs will be much narrower than the contents so their contribution won't really matter.

Comment: Too bad it can't work horizontally too. It seems the layout engine must internally know (or could easily calculate) the width and height of each tab contents item, so it's frustrating not to be able to access this info.

Comment: @thund I just remembered another solution I saw here earlier, which I might be able to integrate. Will have a look if I can find that. Notify when. As is, is this answer good enough to be upvoted and accepted, or it has to cover for both directions?

Comment: I've upvoted this answer since it certainly solves some of the problem, but I'm really hoping for a bi-directional solution for the accepted answer. If there isn't such a solution, perhaps I'll accept this one as the best we can do, but I'll leave it open for a couple of days first.

Comment: How is the tabscontent width being sized now? It certainly doesn't seem to shrink to the width of the tab contents.

Comment: @thund Added some more info.

Comment: @thund I have covered the available options to reach the closest possible what can be done using CSS alone. Do you find this good enough to also be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider `display:grid` instead flex, you might be able to pile each tab within the same spot and size them all according to the widest and tallest:

```css
#tabsthing {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "tab  . ";
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

a {
  grid-area: tab;
}


/* make up for demo purpose */

a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
a {
  border: solid;
  padding: 1em;
  background: turquoise;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

a+a {
  background: tomato;
  text-align: right;
}

a:last-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabsthing">
  <a href="#one">One of three<br/>next line</a>
  <a href="#two">second of three</a>
  <a href="#three"> third of a test about lenght</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pWWQVN

Disclaimer:This might be a dedicated javascript job to be reliable after all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding this sample. Anyhow, my question is really concerning flexbox. To your other point, even if some javascript were required, I think that would be fine, as long as it's robust. I assume for that we'd need to be using the browser's internal layout calculations rather than trying to reproduce too much the layout calcs in js.

Comment: @thund , maybe i do not understand the question. I understood : 2 sibblings element on top of each other sizing themselves to the widest/tallest size of one or the other. the sample stacks here 3 , but it could be 2 or ten , all of them the same size. no absolute positionning involved nor js. position:relative can be used to reorder the stacking order (default is next on top of previous sibbling) Flex cannot do this , absolute remove element from the flow. JS + position seems to be the only option to include any browser :(

Comment: Yes, you are right. My browser colors made one of the items invisible. Sorry - now I see what you are doing. But still it's not flexbox - unless there's a way to mix this in to a flexbox layout.

Comment: Nop, flexbox cannot do this unfortunately :(

Comment: Too bad. It seems there's no logical reason for flexbox not to allow this, and it would be pretty useful. Anyhow, thanks for your answers - they're nice techniques to know about even if they don't quite do everything I'd hoped for this particular case.